Nautilus sendto via bluetooth
I Tried to add sendto option in nautilus file manager for sending files via bluetooth like the windows file manager (send to with various option like bluetooth or email) by using nautilus-sendto and gnome-bluetooth-sendto  but non of thees packages showing the right-click sendto option on nautulus, so is that any way to activate this option on nautilus?
i'm using Debian GNU/Linux trixie/sid with gnome 46?
